# Как получит только те данные у которых количество символов max и min в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Пример таблицы station:

```
id  | city
------------
1   | DEF
------------
2   | ABC
------------
3   | PQRT
------------
4   | SEO
```

Надо выводит только те данные которых количество символов у поля city равно максимальную и минимальную длину символов поля city.

Если количество символов равны, тогда надо брать первую в алфавитном порядке.

Желаемый результат:

```
city  |  length
------------------
ABC   |  3
------------------
PQRT  |  4
```

Буду благодарен за каждый ответ!!!

Comment: Получите в CTE длину каждого значения, во втором MAX/MIN, а в основном запросе отберите подходящие записи. *Желаемый результат* Почему для длины 3 выведено ABC и проигнорированы остальные с той же длиной?

Comment: мы должны выбирать ABC, потому что он идет первым по алфавиту. А извините, что такое СТЕ?

Comment: *что такое СТЕ?* [WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).